# Windows Push Notification Service Failed due to Time Out

Tags: c#, windows, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

The windows push notification fails while trying to establish connection at the following code.

**var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();**

It basically times out with 0x80070102 exception. We have disabled firewall and uninstalled the antivirus but it still fails.

Any suggestions?